# CSS | Grid Template Row Flow if Too Wide

Tags: css, css-grid

Im trying to make a dynamic `grid` that positions its items like this:

- It has a fixed  **`width`**
- In the restrictions of the width, it takes the item one after one, and is supposed to do this:

  - If there's room in the row for the item (the item isn't too wide), place it in the row,
  - else: create a new row and place the item there

I'm basically trying to do something that looks like this:

[image: this]

Comment: This is not a grid but a set of inline-block elements where you don't need any CSS because it's the default behavior

Comment: You're right, guess I was so busy using newer CSS features that I forgot about the basics. :P 
This indeed solved my problem (completely forgot about the option to use inline) so you can post an answer and I'll vote it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex would do the job to keep every row of an even height

```js
//random height/width 
for (let e of document.getElementsByClassName('boxe')) {
  var w = Math.floor(50 + Math.random() * 185) + 'px';
  var h = Math.floor(20 + Math.random() * 25) + 'px';
  e.style.minHeight = h;

  e.style.minWidth = w;
  e.innerHTML = 'min-width:' + w + '\n' + 'min-height: ' + h;
}
```

```css
.flex.boxe {
  max-width: 100%;  /* might be needed*/
  
  /* demo purpose */
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px green, inset 0 0 0 1px green;
  margin: 1px;
  white-space: pre;
  font-size: 10px;
  width:auto;
  border:none;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  /* end demo*/
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: solid #444 5px;
}

.wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex wrap">
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
  <div class="flex boxe"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job made for flexbox, not grid. Good news is it can be done fairly easily by setting `flex-wrap:wrap`:

```css
.flex {
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: solid 2px black;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.flex div {
  height: 40px;
  border: solid 3px green;
}

.flex div:nth-child(5n+1) {flex-basis: 80px}
.flex div:nth-child(5n+2) {flex-basis: 40px}
.flex div:nth-child(5n+3) {flex-basis: 60px}
.flex div:nth-child(5n+4) {flex-basis: 20px}
.flex div:nth-child(5n+5) {flex-basis: 50px}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```